Uploaded PDF Not Downloading In Rails
I have quite a weird situation here in my Rails App.
I have an API call for uploading documents, namely PDFs, which get attached to a Document object via has_one_attached :file in its class definition.
def create
    if can? :create, Document
      @document = Document.new(document_params.except(:upload_files))

      if document_params[:upload_files].present?
        uploaded_file = document_params[:upload_files].first
        @document.file_name = uploaded_file.original_filename
        @document.file_size = uploaded_file.size.to_s
        @document.file_type = uploaded_file.content_type
        @document.file.attach(io: uploaded_file.tempfile, filename: uploaded_file.original_filename, content_type: "application/pdf", identify: false).save
      end

      if @document.save
        redirect_to document_path(@organization, id: @document.id), notice: "Document successfully saved."
      else
        redirect_to root_path, alert: "Document could not be saved."
      end
    else
      raise CanCan::AccessDenied
    end
  end

If I go into a console, and check if the document has an attached file, it returns true:
pry(main)> doc.file.attached?
...
=> true


If I go into the table directly, I can also confirm it is there.
19,file,Document,88,19,2024-12-04 00:55:29.154261


All is well, right? Well, when I use my Download API call, I get a link generated for the file for download:
def download
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        if @document.file.attached?
          file_url = rails_blob_url(@document.file, disposition: "attachment", content_type: @document.file_type)
          render json: { document: { file: file_url } }
        else
          render json: { error: "File not found" }, status: :not_found
        end
      end
      format.html { proxy_attachment_file_render(@document.file) }
    end
  end

I retrieve said link in an AJAX call:
$.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/download/api'
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        if (response.document && response.document.file) {
            const fileUrl = response.document.file;
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = fileUrl;
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        } else {
          alert('File not available for download.');
        }
      },
      error: function() { alert('Error fetching the file.');}
});

But the result I end up with are these empty/nonexistent files in which the browser tells me that the file wasn't available on site.

And so I am a little confused as to how the file is uploaded, attached to the class, and exists, but when I attempt to download the file, it can't be served back. What am I doing incorrect here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What does console.log(response) show?

It returns the URL for the document, something like http://127.0.0.1:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/abcdefghijklmnop/file.pdf. When I click on that, it opens up a window in the browser that attempts to open the file, but returns a modal with the error: Failed to load PDF document.

Okay, I figured it out.
Despite all the evidence pointing to a document being saved, fact of the matter is, it still wasn't properly being persisted by ActiveRecord. So, I had to do a bit of augmentation on how the document was created/persisted:
if document_params[:upload_files].present?
        document_params[:upload_files].each do |file|
          @document = @organization.documents.create(document_params.except(:upload_files))
          @document.file.attach(
            io: File.open(file.tempfile),
            filename: file.original_filename
          )
        end
       @document.save
end

